# Proper subgraphing of a PySpark GraphFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, graphframes

[graphframes](http://graphframes.github.io/quick-start.html) is a network analysis tool based on PySpark DataFrames. The following code is a modified version of the tutorial subgraphing example:

```
from graphframes.examples import Graphs
import graphframes
g = Graphs(sqlContext).friends()  # Get example graph
# Select subgraph of users older than 30
v2 = g.vertices.filter("age > 30")
g2 = graphframes.GraphFrame(v2, g.edges)
```

One would expect that the new graph, `g2` will contain fewer nodes and fewer edges, compared to the original one, `g`. 
However, this is not the case:

```
print(g.vertices.count(), g.edges.count())
print(g2.vertices.count(), g2.edges.count())
```

Gives the output:

```
(6, 7)
(7, 4)
```

It is obvious that the resulting graph contains edges for non-existing nodes.
Even more disturbing is the fact that `g.degrees` and `g2.degrees` are identical. This means that at least some of graph functionality ignores the nodes information.  Is there a good way to make sure that `GraphFrame` creates
a graph using only the intersection of the supplied `nodes` and `edges` arguments?

Answer (score 4):

A method that I use to subgraph a graphframe is using motifs:

```
motifs = g.find("(a)-[e]->(b)").filter(<conditions for a,b or e>)
new_vertices = sqlContext.createDataFrame(motifs.map(lambda row: row.a).union(motifs.map(lambda row: row.b)).distinct())
new_edges = sqlContext.createDataFrame(motifs.map(lambda row:row.e).distinct())
new_graph = GraphFrame(new_vertices,new_edges)
```

While this looks more complicated and possibly takes longer in terms of runtime, for more complicated graph queries, this serves well as you interact with the graphframe as a single entity rather than as vertices and edges being separate. So, filtering on vertices also influences edges left in the graphframe.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting.. I'm not able to see that result:

```
>>> from graphframes.examples import Graphs
>>> import graphframes
>>> g = Graphs(sqlContext).friends()  # Get example graph
>>> # Select subgraph of users older than 30
... v2 = g.vertices.filter("age > 30")
>>> g2 = graphframes.GraphFrame(v2, g.edges)
>>> print(g.vertices.count(), g.edges.count())
(6, 7)
>>> print(g2.vertices.count(), g2.edges.count())
(4, 7)
```

GraphFrames as of now does not check if the graph is valid - ie. all the edges are connects to vertices and so on, at graph construction time. But seems like the number of vertices is correct after the filter?

Comment: > But seems like the number of vertices is correct after the filter?


It is, but not the number of edges. Removing vertices should have resulted in removing some edges too

Answer (score 1):

My work-arounds may not be the perfect ones, but they work for me.

Problem statement as I got it: having a filtered collection of nodes **filtered_nodes**, we only want to have the edges from the original graph that include nodes from **filtered_nodes**.

**Method 1**: Using joins (costly)

```py
edgesframe = graphframe.edges
src_join = edgesframe.join(filtered_nodes, (edgesframe.src == subgraph_nodes.id), "inner").withColumnRenamed("src", "srcto")
dst_join = edgesframe.join(filtered_nodes, (edgesframe.dst == subgraph_nodes.id), "inner").withColumnRenamed("dst", "dstto")
final_join = src_join.join(dst_join, (src_join.src == dst_join.src) & (src_join.dst == dst_join.dst), "inner").select("src", "dst")
g2 = GraphFrame(filtered_nodes, final_join)
```

**Method 2**: Using collected collection as a list-reference for *isin*-method (I'd only use it on small collections of filter nodes)

```py
edgesframe = graphframe.edges
collected_nodes = subgraph_nodes.select("columnWeUseForReference").rdd.map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
edgs = edgesframe.filter(edgesframe.src.isin(collected_nodes) & edgesframe.dst.isin(collected_nodes))
```

Does someone have a better approach? I'd be really happy to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using dropIsolatedVertices().

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).